# How to return (and print) multiple values in a function?

Tags: python-3.x

Here's my code:

```
async def random():
    return 1, 2
idk1, idk2 = random()
print(idk1, idk2)
```

After running, I received the error: cannot unpack non-iterable coroutine object. How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: It appears that your question really is "how do I use coroutines". Is your use of coroutines in your question intentional?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a async function from a synchronized code Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762227/how-to-call-a-async-function-from-a-synchronized-code-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used asyncio.run

```py
import asyncio
async def random():
    return 1, 2
idk1, idk2 = asyncio.run(random())
print(idk1, idk2)
```