# How to make Python async functions callable in Jupyter without await

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, jupyter-notebook

I've written a Python library that currently makes several independent HTTP requests in serial. I'd like to parallelize these requests without altering how the library is called by users, or requiring users to be aware that calls are being made asynchronously under the hood. The library is meant for novice/intermediate Python users mostly using Jupyter, and I'd like it to work without introducing them to unfamiliar `async`/`await` semantics.

The following example, which works in Jupyter, illustrates what I'd like to achieve but requires use of `await` to invoke the code on the final line:

```
import asyncio

async def first_request():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)  # Simulate request time
    return "First request response"

async def second_request():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return "Second request response"

async def make_requests_in_parallel():
    """Make requests in parallel and return the responses."""
    return await asyncio.gather(first_request(), second_request())

results = await make_requests_in_parallel()  # Undesirable use of `await`
```

I've found [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51762699/379798) describing how to call async code from synchronous code using `asyncio.run()`. In the Jupyter example above, I can replace the final line with the following to create a working, importable Python module:

```
def main():
    """Make results available to async-naive users""" 
    return asyncio.run(make_requests_in_parallel())

results = main()  # No `await` needed to get results -- good!
```

This *seems* to be what I want. However, in Jupyter, the code will produce an error:

```
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762227/how-to-call-a-async-function-from-a-synchronized-code-python/51762699#comment123536764_51762699) on the same answer above explains that because Jupyter runs its own async event loop, there is no need (or, apparently, option) to start another one, so async code can "simply" be called using `await`. In my situation, though, avoiding `await` is why I wanted to use `asyncio.run()` in the first place.

This seems to suggest that existing synchronous libraries cannot, by any means, internally parallelize any operation using `asyncio` without altering their public API to require use of `await`. Is this true?

If so, are there more practical alternatives to `asyncio` that would let me parallelize a group of requests in an internal function without educating my users about `async`/`await`?

Answer (score 5):

I found a great solution for this: [nest_asyncio](https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio).

Once installed, the working solution in Jupyter is as follows:

```
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

async def first_request():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)  # Simulate request time
    return "First request response"


async def second_request():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return "Second request response"


async def make_requests_in_parallel():
    """Make requests in parallel and return the responses."""
    return await asyncio.gather(first_request(), second_request())

def main():
    """Make results available to async-naive users""" 
    return asyncio.run(make_requests_in_parallel())

results = main()  # No `await` needed to get results
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. This is by far the cleanest solution I have been looking for as I need to use jupyter as the front end.