# Can not import async function from module in python

Tags: python, asynchronous

I am currently trying to import an (selfwritten) async function in python, but the compiler gives me an error message. See the minimalistic example below (yes I know that in this example async does not really make any sense but for demonstrating purposes I guess it is fine).

In example2.py the complier tells me that ' "await" allowed only within async function Pylance'. If I start the same code in an .ipynb file, the complier still shows the error but if I run it, it works as expected.

My first suspect is that I need to mark the function as async on import but I cannot find anything how I would do this.
My other idea is that it is an Editor problem and that I somehow need to define a exception for the complier. But as I am using *VS Code* I would think that someone would have solved the problem by now.

Does anyone know what the problem is/ how to solve it?
I would like to understand why this problem occures.

example.py:

```
async def add():
    return 1+1
```

example2.py:

```
from example import  add
x =await add()
```

Comment: write an `async` function and inside call `add`, a module is not a `Promise`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a async function from a synchronized code Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762227/how-to-call-a-async-function-from-a-synchronized-code-python)

Comment: @Kemp well it helps to understand the problem but does not answer mine completely.
@rioV8 could you elaborate how this would look and why this does not work? It worked for me when I replaced ```x=await add()``` with 
```x=add();
await x```. Although I would say that both code blocks should be equivalent. Why does one work and the other does not?

Comment: my PyLance does not allow `x = add(); await x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [Python Async/Await doc](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-task.html)

```
import asyncio
from example import add

x = asyncio.run(add())
print(f'x={x}')
```

Calling an `async` function returns a `Promise`.

You have to wait for the Promise generated by calling an `async` function.